# Can we manually throttle the bandwidth of a network interface?

Tags: networking, virtualbox-networking

Say I wish to have the interface eth0 to have a very low bandwidth. 
Is it possible?

As may be evident from the question, I am trying to simulate a network with varying bandwidths.

I am using VirtualBox running Ubuntu to simulate the hosts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can. I never did so but there are already answers on google.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth

https://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface

https://superuser.com/questions/60344/is-there-a-way-to-limit-bandwidth-in-linux

http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle